# Converting Sql to Linq (to Entities)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a query like that and it works normally. If a student gets more than one course, it list all of them:

```
SELECT ks.KullaniciKodu as username, ks.Sifre as password, k.adi as firstname, k.soyadi as lastname, k.Email as email, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.DERSKODU = 'ENF100' THEN 'ENF100' ELSE '' END)As course1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.DERSKODU = 'ATA101' THEN 'ATA101' ELSE '' END) As course2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.DERSKODU = 'TDB101' THEN 'TDB101' ELSE '' END) As course3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN c.DERSKODU = 'İNG101' THEN 'İNG101' ELSE '' END) As course4
FROM Kayit k
JOIN DersNotu dn ON dn.KayitNo = k.KayitNo
JOIN Ders c ON c.DersKayitNo = dn.DersKayitNo AND c.DERSKODU IN ('ENF100','ATA101','TDB101', 'İNG101') AND c.DONEM = '201512'
JOIN KullaniciSifre ks ON ks.KullaniciKodu = k.KullaniciKodu
GROUP BY ks.KullaniciKodu, ks.Sifre, k.adi, k.soyadi, k.Email
```

But when i convert it to Linq (to Entity), it only gets one course or all courses are null. Where is the difference and problem in this code?

```
from k in db.Kayit
join dn in db.DersNotu on k.KayitNo equals dn.KayitNo
join c in db.Ders on dn.DersKayitNo equals c.DersKayitNo
join ks in db.KullaniciSifre on k.KullaniciKodu equals ks.KullaniciKodu
where
     (new string[] { "ENF100", "ATA101", "TDB101", "İNG101" }).Contains(c.DersKodu) &&
     c.Donem == 201512 
group new { ks, k, c } by new
{
     ks.KullaniciKodu,
     ks.Sifre,
     k.Adi,
     k.Soyadi,
     k.Email
     } into g
 select new 
 {
     KullaniciKodu = g.Key.KullaniciKodu,
     Sifre = g.Key.Sifre,
     Adi = g.Key.Adi,
     Soyadi = g.Key.Soyadi,
     Email = g.Max(p => (
         p.k.Email == string.Empty ? "NULL" : p.k.Email)),
     Course1 = g.Max(p => (
         p.c.DersKodu == "ENF100" ? "ENF100,1" : "NULL,1")),
     Course2 = g.Max(p => (
         p.c.DersKodu == "ATA101" ? "ATA101,1" : "NULL,1")),
     Course3 = g.Max(p => (
         p.c.DersKodu == "TDB101" ? "TDB101,1" : "NULL,1")),
     Course4 = g.Max(p => (
         p.c.DersKodu == "İNG101" ? "İNG101,1" : "NULL,1"))
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MAX` in SQL is just a trick to work-around the problem. You should not convert that explicitly to LINQToEntity. The problem here is you use `Max` against strings. In your case the `NULL,1` seems be always selected as max except for the `TDB101,1`.

The actual logic here is such as for `ENF100`, if any one found, project for `"ENF100"`, otherwise project for `"NULL,1"`. The same logic for others. So it should be like this:

```
 Course1 = g.Any(p => p.c.DersKodu == "ENF100") ? "ENF100,1" : "NULL,1",
 Course2 = g.Any(p => p.c.DersKodu == "ATA101") ? "ATA101,1" : "NULL,1",
 Course3 = g.Any(p => p.c.DersKodu == "TDB101") ? "TDB101,1" : "NULL,1",
 Course4 = g.Any(p => p.c.DersKodu == "İNG101") ? "İNG101,1" : "NULL,1"
```

Also the `Email` is projected wrong, it is already included in the group key, so you can just project it via the group key:

```
 Email = g.Key.Email
```